# Progress OpenEdge how to sort by length of char

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

newbie question here.
How can I sort employee table by LEN(Firstname) Desc then by lastName asc?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
output to /usr2/appsrv/test/Test.txt.
def var dRow as char.
for each emp by emp.FirstName no-lock:
  dRow = substitute ("&1,&2", emp.FirstName, emp.LastName).
  put unformatted dRow skip.
end.
put unformatted dRow skip.
output close.
```

I am on version 11.3.3

Thank you

Comment: What does length have to do with this?  You mention it in the title but not in the body.  I'm confused.

Comment: oops sorry I meant to say Lenght of firstname DESC. Original post modified. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for each emp by length( emp.firstName ) descending by lastName:
  display emp.firstName emp.lastName.
end.
```

Performance will stink if this is a large table.

Comment: If this is something that need to be done often and on lots of records you better add a field containing the length of the first name and order by it instead. Remember it need to be updated when the name is updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
for each emp no-lock by emp.FirstName desc by emp.LastName :
```

Comment: sorry I made a mistake on the question. I meant sort by len(firstname) desc then by lastname